# unable to check out a working copy from cornerstone

Tags: svn, archiving, cornerstone

We have a larger enterprise team using Cornerstone to archive/manage our Photoshop work.

Suddenly, we are unable to check out working copies of files from the SVN. We can check out folders, but not the actual files we need to work with.

Comment: You need to give more information about the problem. Are you getting error messages that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

You can not (and nobody never can) `svn co URL/TO/FILE`, only directory

If you checkout empty folders without (existing) files in it, you must check parameters - for some reasons you *may* checkout with `--depth 'empty'` (aliased commands?)